# Avada Wordpress theme - unable to access Branding settings

Tags: permissions, branding, wordpress-admin

We have just commissioned a new website via a commercial designer, who has used Wordpress with Avada theme and Avada Branding. As the owner of the site with an admin login, I am unable to access some Avada settings, and in particular the settings for Avada Branding. The one setting I would like to change is that the word "Avada" is everywhere replaced by our own company name, which is confusing and silly (a bit like installing MS Word and everywhere renaming it "John", IMHO).

The Settings link for the plugin (https:///wp-admin/admin.php?page=avada-white-label-branding-settings) gives "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page".

But it's our site and I have full access via FTP and phpMyAdmin, so how can I unlock access to Avada Branding? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Avada branding is a seperate feature/plugin what needs to be installed. otherwise you will get this error, as the directory the scripts are heading to, dont exist. The separate plugin is just an addition to avadas functionality, thats why the url is recognised, but the plugin is missing. thats why you have *no permission*.